# Is there any way to deploy a demo application in flutter, specifically something made for mobile (regardless of being iOS or Android) on the web?

Tags: flutter, mobile, deployment, demo

I wanted to put my apps demo deploy somewhere, so when I apply for jobs, people can test the apps I made, not just see pictures of the UI and code.

I found a place to do it, appetize.io, but it let you put only 2 apps online.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a mobile Flutter app on the web by building a web version of the application using Flutter's web support. This allows potential employers to test your app in their browsers without needing to install it on their devices.

However, some platform-specific features may not function as expected, so ensure you thoroughly test your app before deploying it as a web demo.

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/building